# HTTP Error 404:File or Directory doesn't exist

Tags: iis, sitecore

I have my local site hosted on IIS and Sitecore.
When i am trying to access the site from my local ex: http://xyz.local/ I am getting the following error as shown in the below image. But i am able to access my local sitecore instance ex: http://xyz.local/sitecore/login.
I have tried checking the permissions for the root folder which has full control for all the users.
also tried some of the solutions but didn't work.

Appreciate any inputs on this.
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Can you compare your web.config with a vanilla web.config. And tell me if this url works /sitecore/shell/sitecore.version.xml

Comment: yes, the url is working.

Comment: Please compare web.configs. What version of Sitecore?

Comment: web.configs looks good. using sitecore 9.0.1

Comment: It looks like your application is redirecting index to 404 error page. So have you checked whehther IIS asp.net feature has been installed? Because your IIS is handling extensionless URL with just staticfile handler.